# TypeORM no connection options found. Suspect issue lies in dist folder and tsconfig

Tags: node.js, database, typescript, typeorm

package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon dist/index.js\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.25"
  }
}
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

File structure:

```
server
 --dist
 --src
   --typeORM
     --entity
       -- User.ts
     --migration
     --index.ts
   --index.ts (express index)
   --ormconfig.json
   --package.json
```

I ran the typeORM cli to get the files and removed and edited some like the package.json since i already had one from setting up express. I also renamed src to typeORM.

ormconfig:

```
{
   "type": "mysql",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 3306,
   "username": "root",
   "password": "",
   "database": "learningTypeORM",
   "synchronize": true,
   "logging": false,
   "entities": [
      "typeORM/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "typeORM/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "typeORM/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "typeORM/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "typeORM/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "typeORM/subscriber"
   }
}
```

express index.ts

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import cors from 'cors';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import { PORT } from './servConsts';
import { router as testRouter } from './routes/test';
import { startConnection } from './typeORM/index';
export const app: express.Application = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));

startConnection();

//root
app.get('/', function (req: Request, res: Response) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.use("/test", testRouter);
//Capture All 404 errors
app.use(function (req: Request, res: Response) {
  res.status(404).send('Unable to find the requested resource!');
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

index.js for typeORM

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
import { User } from "./entity/User";

export function startConnection() {
    createConnection("../ormconfig.json").then(async connection => {

        console.log("Inserting a new user into the database...");
        const user = new User();
        user.firstName = "Timber";
        user.lastName = "Saw";
        user.age = 25;
        await connection.manager.save(user);
        console.log("Saved a new user with id: " + user.id);

        console.log("Loading users from the database...");
        const users = await connection.manager.find(User);
        console.log("Loaded users: ", users);

        console.log("Here you can setup and run express/koa/any other framework.");

    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

When i run `npm run dev` I get

> Error: No connection options were found in any orm configuration
> files. [1]     at ConnectionOptionsReader.
> (..../server/node_modules/typeorm/connection/ConnectionOptionsReader.js:34:35)

I also noticed that the dist folder does not contain the ormconfig json file (not sure why). How do i go about fixing this?

Comment: The reason it's not in your dist folder is very simple. TypeScript does not compile anything except JavaScript. It doesn't do arbitrary file copies. It is nothing in your TS config

Comment: @AluanHaddad is right. You must have a script to copy all you resources that aren't typescript code. Take a look at my project [here](https://github.com/carlocorradini/racer-server) and open *package.json | build.json | script/build.ts*. In the build.json you can specify where and what to copy. In package.json when *npm run build* has finished the build.ts script is executed. build.ts read the build.json file and copy every file/s and folder/s you specified. Hope it helps :)